# Does 32:4 negate intercession in the afterlife?

Tags: tafseer, shafaah

> It is Allah who created the heavens and the earth and whatever is between them in six days; then He established Himself above the Throne. You have not besides Him any protector or any intercessor; so will you not be reminded

it says that we don't have intercessors ; there are other verses about intercession but how  do i reconcile with this verse; is it talking to the disbelievers ?

i found the tafsir ibn kathir https://quran.com/32:4/tafsirs/en-tafisr-ibn-kathir

Comment: It would be good if you shared the verses you are referring to an not only the one you think that seems to contradict. So that we have a common understanding on what you mean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same verse, Allah says: "no protector/ally (wali) [...] except Allah."

In another verse, Allah says:

> The believing men and believing women are allies of one another. [...] (9:71)

So, it is obvious that the meaning is not literally no allies except Allah.

Then, what does it mean? It means no one has an ally in truth or an intercessor in truth except Allah, because all alliance/protection and all intercession is by His permission alone. Even if there is intercession, it is only because of Allah and from Allah and truly Allah's intercession.

Similarly, Allah says in another place: "you have not besides Allah any protector or any helper."

Someone could say: But, my friend helps me!

But, that is not the meaning of the verse. All help comes from Allah through His permission.

Answer (score 0):

i guess i found an answer

when you say you have an intercessor , it's a guarantee that you have one  ; Also it's not necessarily talking about matters on the day of judgement ; Rather it's the affairs of our lives and day of judgement i.e everything ;  everything is in Allah's control  and if Allah does something to us ; there is no one who can protect us from Allah nor intercede just like that without Allah's permission. Do you get the meaning InshaAllah ?
So there is nobody who can intercede ; you might find this verse contradictory  but Allah says : you do not have any intercessors ; 
So if we don't have any intercessors that mean there is no guaranteed intercessors ; it's what intercessor means; because you can't be an intercessors if you don't intercede;  i guess

Also in general life people can't intercede , because an intercessors is someone who always guaranteed can intercede , thus in the verse that we don't have anyone .Because in the verse Allah is talking about everything he does to us ; no one can intercede or will intercede probably for everything Allah will do to us

Because if we had intercessors besides Allah ; they wouldn't properly be intercessors if they can't or don't  intercede for everything Allah does to us.
Anyways Allah is probably talking about intercessors that are there for us by default ; without  Allah's permission

i think i complicated the answer ; the verse means probably
ibn kathir :
(You have none, besides Him, as a protector or an intercessor) means, only He is the Sovereign Who is in control of all affairs, the Creator of all things, the Controller of all things, the One Who is able to do all things. There is no Creator besides Him, no intercessor except the one to whom He gives permission.

So by default we don't have any intercessors who are not bound to Allah's permission ;; we have intercessors only  when Allah gives someone permission

Do you guys agree  comment down

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).